# Elasticsearch: are all possible GET requests always non-destructive, idempotent, and safe?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

Are there any destructive calls that can be invoked with a HTTP GET calling Elasticsearch?

Examples of "destructive" might include actions such as delete items/delete indexes/change settings... pretty much anything that can modify settings/state of the Elasticsearch or the data.

I want to make an operational command line tool which would allow any arbitrary `GET` request to elastic search if `GET` requests are safe. So there isn't worry about DDOS attacks or anyone on purpose being malicious since operational tool will only be accessible to engineers.

Comment: Why do you want to know this? Are you trying to protect your elastic with server access rules?

Comment: I want to have an operational tool which would allow arbitrary GET calls if the get calls aren't destructive.

Comment: My experience with elasticsearch is too limited to give a definitive answer, and hopefully we have someone here who can answer this more directly.  A properly-designed API means `GET` never changes any state.  There are, though, more considerations than this, such as the denial-of-service potential from heavy loading or particularly expensive queries, so the answer you are looking for may not be the full answer.  I would suggest that any exposed service should be wrapped in another API, even if it's an identical API that re-canonicalizes the incoming request using only elements it understands.